# Android API webservice for drop down and multilanguage support

Tags: android, rest, drop-down-menu

Exploring if there is a better way to do this, my current solution is:

I have an Android app that needs to pull data from server through API to display at a drop down list. Example data is

```
 id | text
 ----------
 x  | banana
 x  | orange
 x  | apple
```

I also need to have multi language support.
Using Android Studio, i created a **staging** and **production** strings.xml.

Inside my **values** strings.xml file it contains:

```
<string name="banana">Banana</string>
<string name="apple">Apple</string>
<string name="orange">Orange</string>
```

and inside **values-ms** (different language than default) strings.xml:

```
<string name="banana">pisang</string>
<string name="apple">epal</string>
<string name="orange">oren</string>
```

and at **staging** strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="fruits_id">
    <item>2|@string/banana</item>
    <item>3|@string/orange</item>
    <item>4|@string/apple</item>
</string-array>
```

and at **production** strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="fruits_id">
    <item>1|@string/banana</item>
    <item>2|@string/orange</item>
    <item>3|@string/apple</item>
</string-array>
```

Notice that the numbers in front of string-array are actual database ID and it can differ from staging database to production database, hence I split it into different strings.xml files.

When a user select values "apple" from a drop down list, I want to **display the values** according to user's language setting suchs as displaying either "apple" or "epal" in this scenario.

If this is a production scenario, my webservice will return the value "3" to server

Inside this page it has 10 drop down / spinner, thus I prefer not to load value from API when starting this page/activity and hard code my available selections into app

Is this the most efficient way to support getting database id of selected drop down choice and at the same time can use multiple language?

Comment: Is storing the translated items on the database not possible? I would think you could set a users language preference, and than when you make a call to the API pass the language abbrevation, such as, EN or RU. Then on the backend it will pull the correct data and send it back through the response. You could have 1 table with an id column, and many language columns and just query on ID and Language Value.

Comment: I would strongly suggest against exposing the database's id as the value of the webservice. It generally can cause more issues in the future.

Comment: @AvinashR in that case how would you communicate back to server on which value user selected? I originally thought of ID as its a column that is indexed (which means query runs faster when I have 10 tables join) rather than I query database by value (example select xxx from xx where name = 'apple' )

Comment: @simeh, you can index the field that you use for selection. Anyway that is not my point. the point is that if you tie your API with the database, it'll create a new set of problems altogether. Say you are going to back your business logic tomorrow with a no-sql, how do you expect yourself to bring the change without changing the Android app? By using an intermediary value, you are free to use any backend you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use hardcoded IDs. They are very hard to maintain. I would do the following instead:

Example data remains the same:

```
id | text
----------
x  | banana
x  | orange
x  | apple
```

Inside your values strings.xml file:

```
<string name="banana">Banana</string>
<string name="apple">Apple</string>
<string name="orange">Orange</string>
```

and inside values-ms (different language than default) strings.xml:

```
<string name="banana">pisang</string>
<string name="apple">epal</string>
<string name="orange">oren</string>
```

Create a simple class for the received data such as:

```
public class MyItem {

    public long id;

    public String key;

    public String value;

    public MyItem(long id, String key, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Load the data for all spinners and store them somewhere: e.g. in the shared preferences.

```
dataList
```

Then create a list of **MyItem** from the received data:

```
final List<MyItem> myItemList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
for (data in dataList) {
    myItemList.add(new MyItem(data.id, data.key, getString(data.key)));
}
```

Then create an array adapter for your drop-down. Please note that the toString() method of MyItem is overridden ... so the simple array adapter will work as expected:

```
yourSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myItemList));
```

Then you can check the selected item by calling:

```
final MyItem selectedItem = (MyItem) yourSpinner.getSelectedItem();
```

Now you can see (and send back to the server) the selected **ID**.

```
selectedItem.id
```

Comment: I have many spinner inside a single page, about 10. In order to load fast, I prefer not to pull API request during this page load. Your solution doesn't address about multi language support, which i need to display to user in their language once they select a value at spinner

Comment: You don't have to pull API requests during the page load. You can store the received values e.g. in the shared preferences and use them whenever you want. My version supports multi language as well. I mentioned that you don't have to modify your strings.xml files.

Comment: Your solution is to store translated value at database instead of at Android like mentioned by ItzHoudini above?

Comment: No no. My suggestion is to delete those string-array items and instead create a list of class and use them for the spinner. Everything else remains unchanged. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is fine so far but instead of creating 2 different file "staging" and "production", i will recommend you to create instead two flavor in your project gradle, staging and production. And place both file int he appropriate folder and i can guarantee you that the both ID will be the same.

PS : note that you will have to build different apks base on the buildVariant (flavor + builtype)

Example if you want to have access to your staging file you will have to build a separate apk, that is how flavor work and i hope that it is what you are looking for.

Have a look a this links about flaovrs
[LINK1](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example) [LINK2](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) (scroll down a bit for flavor) 
Last but not least take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JDEK4wkN5I)

Edit: you will have to use different copy in both flavor translation to match the production and staging "ID"

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This solution assumes that the number of items in the dropdown(Spinner) remains unchanged throughout the app*

What you should be doing is create an enum as the *model* of each item in the spinner.

```
public enum Fruit {
 APPLE(R.string.apple), BANANA(R.string.banana), ORANGE(R.string.banana);
 @StringRes
 public int resId;
 @Override
 public String toString() {
    // you can use the application context here or 
    // can overload the toString as toString(Context)
    ctx.getString(resId);
 }
}
```

then in the `strings.xml`

```
<string name="apple">Apple</string>
<string name="banana">Banana</string>
<string name="orange">Orange</string>
<string-array name="fruits">
    <item>@string/banana</item>
    <item>@string/orange</item>
    <item>@string/apple</item>
</string-array>
```

in `values-ms/string.xml`

```
<string name="banana">pisang</string>
<string name="apple">epal</string>
<string name="orange">oren</string>
```

Use the `R.string.fruits` in your adapter(ArrayAdapter?) and call the overrided(or overloaded)`toString` method when you populate the view.

now if you need different values to give in the web service, you can provide different implementations of the `Fruit` enum based on the code above and it'll work right out of the box without any effect on i18n

### Refs:

1. [`@StringRes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringRes.html)

Comment: Avinash, how is your solution different from Blehi's answer

Comment: @simeh, for one, it's cleaner (IMO). second it's easier to maintain. Also blehi's answer can be used if you want the spinner be generated fully from the backend (also can be cached locally on the device to reduce the db hits), My solution however _assumes_ that the spinner list is immutable throughout the application. Though it provides multi-language support in a saner and concise manner.